# Streaming to VAO VertexBuffer using OpenGL Direct State Access for Instancing

Tags: opengl, instancing, vertex-buffer, vertex-arrays, vao

How do i stream to a vertex buffer using Direct State Access? I want to update my vertex buffer of matrices every frame so i can use it in my Shader. 
This is how i specify my buffer. I do this once in my application when i initialize my VAO.

```
    glNamedBufferStorage(StaticModelData::instanceDataID, sizeof(InstanceData)*10, nullptr, 0);
    glMapNamedBufferRange(StaticModelData::instanceDataID, 0, sizeof(InstanceData) * 10, GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT);
    glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(StaticModelData::vaoID, 1, StaticModelData::instanceDataID, 0, 0);

    glVertexArrayAttribBinding(StaticModelData::vaoID, 3, 1);
    glVertexArrayAttribFormat(StaticModelData::vaoID, 3, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);

    glVertexArrayAttribBinding(StaticModelData::vaoID, 4, 1);
    glVertexArrayAttribFormat(StaticModelData::vaoID, 4, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 4);

    glVertexArrayAttribBinding(StaticModelData::vaoID, 5, 1);
    glVertexArrayAttribFormat(StaticModelData::vaoID, 5, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 8);

    glVertexArrayAttribBinding(StaticModelData::vaoID, 6, 1);
    glVertexArrayAttribFormat(StaticModelData::vaoID, 6, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 12);

    glVertexArrayBindingDivisor(StaticModelData::vaoID, 1, 1);
```

Every frame i do this to render

```
    instanceDatas = updateMatrices();    
    updateShader();
    glBindVertexArray(StaticModelData::vaoID);
    glNamedBufferData(StaticModelData::instanceDataID, sizeof(InstanceData)*(instanceDatas.size()), &instanceDatas[0], 0);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1);//hardcoded

    glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, it->second.modelIndexNum, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)(sizeof(int)*(it->second.indexOffset)), it->second.instances.size());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question has nothing to do with direct state access. Your problems would still happen if you weren't using DSA functions.

> ```
> glNamedBufferStorage(StaticModelData::instanceDataID, sizeof(InstanceData)*10, nullptr, 0);
> ```

That last value tells OpenGL [how you intend to access the storage from the CPU](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object#Immutable_access_methods). By passing zero, you're saying that you're *not* going to access the storage from the CPU. *At all*. Since you made a promise not to access its storage from the CPU, OpenGL doesn't let you break that promise.

Furthermore, since you created [immutable storage](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object#Immutable_Storage) for this buffer, you cannot later call `glNamedBufferData` or `glNamedBufferStorage` on the buffer.

The general [buffer streaming techniques](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming) don't change just because you're using DSA. Personally, since you're using immutable storage buffers anyway, I'd say that you should use [persistent&coherent mapped memory with your buffers](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming#Persistent_mapped_streaming).

So you should create your buffer with `MAP_WRITE_BIT`, `PERSISTENT_BIT`, and `COHERENT_BIT`. You should map it once (with those bits too) and just keep the pointer around.

Now, you should still double-buffer your instances, so that you're not overwriting data that the GPU is still reading from.